# 1/4 cup of whiskey in cupcake batter substitute what type of liquid? And use the same amount?

Tags: substitutions

I'm making chocolate coffee cupcakes with pecan praline centers. 1/4 cup of whiskey to batter. I don't want alcohol and don't know what the purpose of the alcohol is. Can I use some other liquid and the same amount?

Answer (score 4):

The whiskey is there to add flavor. If it were in the praline centers it might have some texture effect too, but in the batter, especially in this small an amount, it's really only going to matter for flavor.

You should be able to substitute water, plus an appropriate amount of some kind of flavored extract you *do* want - vanilla, rum, or anything that sounds good to you. (If alcohol is a problem I guess you'll need an alcohol-free one.) You could also simply find another recipe that doesn't use it.

That said, if it's just that you don't want to buy a whole bottle of whiskey, you can likely get a tiny bottle to use just for this recipe, and not have a ton left over. If you suspect you wouldn't like the flavor, do keep in mind that a quarter cup of whiskey is a pretty small amount of alcohol when spread across a whole batch of cupcakes, so it could be worth giving it a try. But if you really just don't want to consume any alcohol, water should be fine.

Comment: I mostly agree with this. I probably wouldn't sub straight water though. Alcohol doesn't contribute to gluten formation like water does, so just plain water could make the cupcakes chewier. (Careful mixing could mitigate this, but as long as you're subbing I'd use coffee or something with flavor)

Comment: @sourd'oh: Coffee is at least 95% water ([source](http://coffeeandhealth.org/all-about-coffee/nutrition-information/)), versus 50-60% for whiskey.  So if you're concerned about water having an effect on the texture, I'd expect coffee to do the same.  Other than alcohol and oils, I can't think of too many other edible liquids that aren't almost entirely water.

Comment: @sourd'oh I did gloss over that, but basically, it's only an eighth of a cup of extra water at 100 proof, so I really don't think it's anything you need to worry about. Maybe they'll be *slightly* less tender, but it's not like you're going to find another non-water liquid to use.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't think it's going to make or break it. What I meant with the coffee is that if I'm adding water anyway, I'd rather add something like coffee that will actually add some flavor too. Honestly, I'd think they'd probably turn out ok if you left out the whiskey and didn't sub anything else.

Comment: @sourd'oh Oh, I did say to use some kind of extract along with the water, figured that was more likely to work out given that whiskey is a fairly strong flavor.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I bought some Madagascar vanilla vodka today for next time!